# Can I get payer_id with "Login with Paypal"?

Tags: paypal

I'm integrating Log In with PayPal - JavaScript Button.
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/log-in-with-paypal/js_button/

I need "payer_id" of the user who logged in with paypal.
But it's NOT included in a response.

A response of "4. Get User's PayPal Profile Data" in above integration guide is like this :

`{
    "family_name":"Ito",
    "name":"Gen Ito",
    "account_type":"BUSINESS",
    "given_name":"Gen",
    "user_id":"ttps://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/identity/user/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "verified_account":"true",
    "language":"ja_JP",
    "zoneinfo":"Asia/Tokyo",
    "locale":"ja_JP",
    "email":"xxx@xxx",
    "account_creation_date":"2011-11-18",
    "birthday":"1982-08-02",
    "age_range":"26-30"
}`

"payer_id" is listed in below, so I thought payer_id is available.
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#get-user-information

Can I get payer_id with "Login with Paypal" ?
Then should I use another/other request ?

Comment: It is a restricted attribute, you have to request access to it. Don't know how, support and github did not help, we had someone to contact paypal.

Answer (score 1):

you need to submit a support ticket at www.paypal.com/mts and request access to this attribute.

Comment: Hello, I've ran into the exact same problem as explained above. Can you tell me if contacting mts to request access to this attribute was successful? I have requested exactly that, but their response was: " 
I apologise but you have contacted the wrong department,
Merchant Technical Services only deal with technical issues regarding our products.
 
I don't have the access to find this information for you.
 
You should contact customer services and they will be able to help you."