# How do I obtain a PayPal user's payer_id through OpenID Connect?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm authenticating a PayPal user using the REST OpenID Connect API, which let's me access the [userinfo](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#get-user-information) information for that user.

I'd like to use this information to be able to send money to that user through the Adaptive Payments API. I know I can use their email address for this, but email addresses change, so I'd like to use the `accountId` field instead, which I believe is the same as the `payer_id` visible the Express Checkout APIs, and should be a consistent, unique ID.

However, despite the `payer_id` field being documented in the userinfo response, I don't see that information in the response. I can see `user_id`, which looks like a URL, and doesn't seem to contain the same identifier.

Is it possible to get a `payer_id` out of the REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see from this answer that you have to ask for this attribute:

[Can I get payer_id with "Login with Paypal"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715649/can-i-get-payer-id-with-login-with-paypal)